# How do I use the asp.net configuration tool once the website is deployed

Tags: asp.net

I understand that the configuration tool can be opened via VS2010. 
But how do I open this tool for my application deployed on server?

Comment: You can't, what exactly are you needing it for?

Comment: I need it for modifying my users, roles, access rules once the website is live. The asp.net configuration tool can be used for a web application locally on the machine. How do I use the tool for an application on the server?

Comment: You can't use it in Production. And you don't really need to. Just open the Web.config in Notepad and make your changes.

Comment: How do I do authentication and authorization via web.config file.
Can you show me an article how to do it?

Comment: Are you needing a new role entirely, do you need to add a user to a role, what specifically do you need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading the required web.config files for all authorized folders and everything works fine.